# Create a dataframe with list of desired inputs and sourcing from different dataframe in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists of lists, which is very long, but it has this format: `[[['14-Sep-20'], 'a'], [['10-Jan-20','21-May-21'], 'b'], [['10-Jan-20'], 'c'], [['25-Feb-21'], 'd']]`

then I have a dataframe with all the dates from 1.1.2020 to the current day, for all the companies a-z and each cell has a value in hundreds:

| Date | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-20 | 450 | 750 | -450 | 750 | 450 |
| 2-Jan-20 | 350 | 780 | 400 | 500 | 500 |
| 3-Jan-20 | 400 | 500 | 700 | 900 | 600 |

What I want is to create a dataframe which will have dates from the list as index, companies from the list as columns and then the appropriate cells filled with the `df1`  data
desired df:

| Date | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan-20 |  | 750 | -450 |  |
| 14-Sep-20 | 350 |  |  |  |
| 25-Feb-21 |  |  |  | 900 |
| 21-May-21 |  | -600 |  |  |

As you can see, the desired df has filled in the appropriate cells, with each company having data only on the appropriate dates from the list.

I have already tried changing the data to a dictionary and setting a dataframe like that:

```
data = {'10-Jan-20':{'b':750,'c':-450},'14-Sep-20':{'a':350},'25-Feb-21':{'d':900},'21-May-21':{'b':-600}}
print(pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','URW.AS','VIV.PA','URW.AS','VOWG.DE']))
```

but this didnt work. Also note that this is not the best approach as I manually pasted some of the cell values and I would need to modify this so that it would outsource it from the `df1` frame automatically.

Thank you

**EDIT**

After @Ynjxsjmh answers, I implemented the code; and I got a dataframe with correct dates and columns, however, all the cells are NaN - even when there should be the one displayed from df2.

| Date | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan-20 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 14-Sep-20 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 25-Feb-21 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 21-May-21 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
lsts = [[['14-Sep-20'], 'a'], [['10-Jan-20','21-May-21'], 'b'], [['10-Jan-20'], 'c'], [['25-Feb-21'], 'd']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(lsts).explode(0)
df2 = pd.crosstab(df2[0], df2[1]).astype(bool)
out = df1.set_index('Date').reindex_like(df2).where(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it says `ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64`   I checked the df['Date'] data type and it is datetime64. Should I convert the dates in df1 to floats?

Comment: please check the edit